# Add on for firefox for custom search providers - ike IE does?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

In IE you are able to add a custom search provider in Firefox? IE does this nicely and lets you add any site as a search provider.

Is there anything similar? For example to add godaddy.com as a search provider that will allow you to search for a domain from the Firefox search box.

Answer (score 0):

The firefox search provider model is not as user friendly as IE.  IE has nicely separated it's search providers from it's addons, but Firefox lumps them all together.  IE also allows you to create them easily on the fly, as far as I can tell, Firefox does not.

Here is a quick search for addons that can be used as search providers:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?atype=4&q=search+provider&y=0&x=0

For the specific domain search from godaddy.com you mentioned, here is a pretty good one:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7095/